# Haskell: brute force and maximum subarray problem

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am trying to solve the [maximum sub array problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadane%27s_Algorithm) with a brute force approach i.e generating all the possible subarrays combinations. I got something that works but it's not satisfying at all because it produces way too many duplicated subarrays.

Does anyone knows a smart way to generate all the subarrays (in [[]] form) with a minimal number of duplicated elements ?

By the way, I'm new to Haskell. Here's my current solution:

```
import qualified Data.List as L

maximumSubList::[Integer]->[Integer]
maximumSubList x = head $ L.sortBy (\a b -> compare (sum b) (sum a)) $ L.nub $ slice x
     where 
        -- slice will return all the "sub lists"
        slice [] = []
        slice x = (slice $ tail x) ++ (sliceLeft x) ++ (sliceRight x)

        -- Create sub lists by removing "left" part
        -- ex [1,2,3] -> [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
        sliceRight [] = []
        sliceRight x = x : (sliceRight $ tail x)

        -- Create sub lists by removing "right" part
        -- ex [1,2,3] -> [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1]]
        sliceLeft [] = []
        sliceLeft x = x : (sliceLeft $ init x)
```

Comment: Just as a note, you're using linked lists, not arrays, so your algorithm won't have the array complexity you may be expecting.

Comment: @DonStewart You are right I am using lists. Actually I mentionned "array" in my description because of the problem's name ("maximum subarray"), bad idea I guess

Comment: I had to giggle at "I'm using a brute force approach ... but it's not satisfying at all...".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many useful functions for operating on lists in the standard [Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) module.

```
import Data.List

slice :: [a] -> [[a]]
slice = filter (not . null) . concatMap tails . inits
```

Comment: concatMap tails.inits this is perfect, it is exactly what I wanted to produce (my brain is not ready yet...). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[dave4420's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424383/47984) is how to do what you want to do using smart, concise Haskell.  I'm no Haskell expert, but I occasionally play around with it and find solving a problem like this to be an interesting distraction, and enjoy figuring out exactly why it works.  Hopefully the following explanation will be helpful :)

The key property of dave4420's answer (which your answer doesn't have) is that the pair `(startPos, endPos)` is unique for each subarray it generates.  Now, observe that two subarrays are distinct if *either* their `startPos` or `endPos` is different.  Applying `inits` to the original array returns a list of subarrays that each have unique `startPos`, and the same `endPos` (equal to the number of elements in the array).  Applying `tails` to each of these subarrays in turn produces another list of subarrays -- one list of subarrays is output per input subarray.  Notice that `tails` *does not disturb the distinctness between input subarrays* because the subarrays output by invoking `tails` on a single input subarray all retain the same `startPos`: that is, if you have two subarrays with distinct `startPos`es, and put both of them through `tails`, each of the subarrays produced from the first input subarray will be distinct from each of the subarrays produced from the second one.

Additionally, each of the subarrays produced by the invocation of `tails` on a single subarray are distinct because, although they all share the same `startPos`, they all have distinct `endPos`es.  Therefore all subarrays produced by `(concatMap tails) . inits` are distinct.  It only remains to note that no subarray is missed out: for any subarray starting at position `i` and ending at position `j`, that subarray must appear as the `j-i+1`th list produced by applying `tails` to the `i+1`th list produced by `inits`.  So in conclusion, every possible subarray appears exactly once!